# Microsoft Access - Add all items from a listbox into a table without having to be selected?

Tags: vba, ms-access, listbox

I'm making a data entry form that allows me to add new businesses and details for that business, before importing them into their respective tables. For the most part, I have completed it all.

However, there are some pieces of information that require more than one input. For example - a business could have multiple telephone numbers/documents/staff members etc.

I have set up a text box and an add/remove button which adds/removes the text in the textbox to a listbox. I want to be able to import all of the items in the listbox, without having to select them into a table. Is this possible? Most of the answers that I've found online require you to have the items selected.

An example piece of code that I have on the import button is show below. This code adds the address details of the business to the 'Business Address' table.

```
'Set Table to 'Business Address' then add the fields to the table
Set RST = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Business Address", dbOpenTable)
RST.AddNew
RST![Business Name] = Me.txtBusinessName
RST![Address] = Me.txtAddress1 & ", " & Me.txtAddress2
RST![Town/City] = Me.txtTownCity
RST![Postal Code] = Me.txtPostalCode
RST.Update
RST.Close
```

I was thinking some sort of for loop to add all items in the listbox to a table?

Logically speaking **(This is not a real example of working code, just something I imagine this might look like if possible?):**

```
Set RST = CurrentDb.OpernRecordset("Business Telephone", dbOpenTable)
For each item in TelephoneListBox
    Rst.AddNew
    Rst![Business Name] = Me.txtBusinessName
    Rst![Telephone] = Me.TelephoneListBox.Column(0)
```

I'm not sure how to go about it and if it can actually be done without the items being selected? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim l As Long

For l = 0 To Me.List0.ListCount - 1

    '   Debug.Print Me.List0.ItemData(l) or me.list0.column(0,l)

Next l
```

This will loop through the items in the list.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working correctly. My list has the items (Test 1, Test 2 and Test 3), but your code only seems to print:

Test 3
Test 3
Test 3

Comment: I've made a suggested edit that fixes your code. It now prints each item in the list; rather than printing the last item multiplied by the amount of items in the list

Answer (score 0):

To improve on Nathan_Sav's answer:

```
Dim i As Long
Set RST = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Business Telephone", dbOpenTable)

For i = 0 To Me.TelephoneListBox.ListCount - 1
        RST.AddNew
        Rst![Business Name] = Me.txtBusinessName
        RST![Telephone] = Me.TelephoneListBox.Column(0, i)
        RST.Update

Next i
```

Adds the value of **'txtBusinessName'** to the table **'Business Telephone'**, under the field specified (**Business Name**), for each item that is in the listbox.

Also adds all items in the listbox (**TelephoneListBox**) to the same table under the field specified (**Telephone**).